# AES Decrypted password does not match to plain password

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

Sorry for if this question has been asked but i couldn't find.

I have an AES 128 encrypted password,

```
 0oebFpht20TMB20alRs4IMMMgIeMObvYsD1/8rUtyq8=
```

I did it decrypt,

```
$decrypt_password = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ciphertext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo $decrypt_password;
output:   Red@(Eye4u)
```

i am getting correct plain password but when i am trying to compare decrypted password with another plain password, it does not match.

```
$another_pass = "Red@(Eye4u)";

if($another_pass == $decrypt_password) {
      //Not going there
}
else if(strcmp($another_pass, $decrypt_password) == 0) {
      //Not going there
}

else if(strcmp($another_pass, $decrypt_password)){
      //Performing this
}
```

I tried to check the return value,

```
echo strcmp($another_pass, $decrypt_password);
output: -5

echo strcmp($decrypt_password, $another_pass);
output: 5
```

so please help how to solve this problem, why it is returning difference where both password is same.

Comment: Passwords should not be encrypted, they should be one-way hashed, with http://php.net/password_hash.

Comment: This is not strictly advice for PHP, but generally passwords should be stored in their hashed form. When a user is logging in, the password that the user types should be hashed and then the two are compared to see if they are 'equal'.  
There should not be a way to decode the passwords that you are storing.  
Here is a handy video to help explain this thoroughly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoMOAIzBSpY

Answer (score 3):

If you use PHP mcrypt then you have to perform (PKCS#7 compatible) padding yourself.

Otherwise PHP will perform padding of 0 to 15 zero valued bytes. Those bytes are not automatically stripped off. If you are sure that the input is ASCII or UTF-8 compatible then you can simply strip off the rightmost zero bytes using `rtrim($str, "\0")`.

Now the documentation of `strcmp` indicates that it performs: "Binary safe string comparison". So if the password doesn't contain the zero valued bytes it will of course fail.

Comment: @mylogon doesn't provide a direct answer, but it's true that if you can only use password hashing then you should choose that over encryption/decryption. Password hashes are irreversible (unless the password is guessed correctly) so there is less chance of the passwords becoming available to an attacker.